# How to get cordova version number from a APK file build using cordova.

Tags: android, cordova

I have an android APK file, I want to know the cordova-cli version using that this apk file was build, so I just decompile that apk and tried to find cordova version number but I didn't find that, Please someone help me that in which file I can find cordova version number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your APK with an archive tool like 7z.

[image]

Open the following folder:

```
assets\www\
```

You will find a file:

```
cordova.js
```

Open the file. In line 22 you will find:

```
var PLATFORM_VERSION_BUILD_LABEL = '7.0.0';
```

This gives you the info about the Android version.

If you build with Phonegap and want to now know the used CLI, take a look here:

https://build.phonegap.com/current-support

In my example, I used Android version 7.0.0 and Phonegap CLI 8.0.0

Comment: I am using Cordova and want to know the Cordova CLI version that used to build a particular apk.